# Configure services based on env var in Symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a project that uses many env vars and I used php files (rather than yaml files or xml) to deal with configurations.

I am trying to this code :

```php
    // config/may_conf_name.php
    
    return static function (ContainerConfigurator $containerConfigurator): void {
       $containerConfigurator->extension('my_extension', [
           ...
       ]);
    
        // CLIENT_TYPE is an env variable
        if ('http' === (string) env('CLIENT_TYPE')->string()) {
            $services->alias(AbstractClient::class, HttpClient::class);
        } else {
            $services->alias(AbstractClient::class, AwsClient::class);
        }
        
        ...
    }
```

Unfortunately, `env('CLIENT_TYPE')->string())` isn’t parsed

```php
dump(
    (string) env('CLIENT_TYPE')->string())
)

// output
^ "%env(string:CNT_CLIENT_TYPE)%"
```

Obviously, when I do this, it works for me :

```php
    if (isset($_ENV['CLIENT_TYPE']) && 'http' === $_ENV['CLIENT_TYPE']) {
       ....
    }
```

So, my question is there a way to get my ‘CLIENT_TYPE’ env var like `env('CLIENT_TYPE')->string()`? Is it "clean" to do this with `$_ENV['CLIENT_TYPE']`?

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of symfony are you using ?

Comment: I am using Symfony 5.4

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#binding-arguments-by-name-or-type

In your service.yaml or php in your case you can bind variable which will be autoimported inside autowired services.

In Yaml

```
 bind:
    $clientType: '%env(CLIENT_TYPE)%'
```

In php

```
->bind('$clientType', '%env(CLIENT_TYPE)%')
```

Then in any service where you want to use your environment var :

```
public function __construct(string $clientType)
```

`$clientType` will be autowired automatically with your binded configuration.

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, dont hesitate to comment i will update my answer, but i hope it will at least give you an idea of what to do.

I asked for your SF version because autowiring is automatically working on 5.4 if you did not disabled it

If CLIENT TYPE is empty, it is not related to your symfony configuration. It mean that your env var is not properly written to your current env file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I needed is how to configure a service based on `env` vars and why the Symfony env function is not returning the value of that environment variable

Comment: @HoussemZITOUN my answer directly answer to "how to configure a service based on env vars", If it is not working it is because your env var is not properly set somewhere else. Please update your question with an exemple of your .env file